Need to understand OverflowException exception
Can someone please help me to know why below piece of code giving me Overflow exception even if I use long and double datatype of variable numValue:
tring[] inputValues = new string[] { "3", "9999999999", "0", "2" };
        foreach (string inputValue in inputValues)
        {
            long numValue = 0;
            try
            {
                numValue = int.Parse(inputValue);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid readResult. Please enter a valid number.");
            }
            catch (OverflowException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The number you entered is too large or too small.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

I tried changing the data type of numValue variable.

You're using int.Parse, which only supports the signed 32-bit integer limits. Even if you're then assigning that result into a long (or double) variable, int.Parse itself will still overflow.
Change your code to use long.Parse or double.Parse, depending on if you want floating-point numbers or not.
...
long numValue = 0;
try
{
    numValue = long.Parse(inputValue);
}
catch (FormatException)
{
...

